# october cms create models from database table

Tags: php, laravel, content-management-system

I' m developing a plugin for october cms. But I have yet a database with table on mySQL. Now I'm looking for a methods to autogenerate "models" based on the database table.
I' m looking for somethings like the laravel command

```
php artisan code:models
```

to work on the plugin.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe what youre looking for is:

`php artisan create:model Acme.Blog Post`

The create:model command generates the files needed for a new model. The first parameter specifies the author and plugin name. The second parameter specifies the model class name.

reference: https://octobercms.com/docs/console/scaffolding#scaffold-create-model

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for somethings to create model by reading table from a database that already exist...

Comment: I'm not sure that's a thing with October. You'll most likely have to write a migration by hand or find some software to do it for you.